# How to retrieve data from file in c++

Tags: c++, file

I have a txt file with this format:

```
<Year> <count>
1999   5.4
1989   5
1993   55.4
```

I have to get each year and count from the file, convert the year in to `int` and count in to `double` and store them in arrays.

> Problem: it shows random huge negative numbers

```
stringstream line;
  string a;
  int year;
  double count;
  ifstream myfile(path);
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
   getline(myfile, a); //getting rid of the first line.
   while (getline(myfile, a))
   {
    cout << a << '\n';
    line >> year >> count;
    cout << "year:" << year << endl;
    cout << "count:"<< count << endl;

   }
   myfile.close();
```

Comment: Use `std::stringstream` here is the documentation and example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/

Comment: Hey I updated my post with your advice. I used Stringstream but Now I get negative random numbers instead of the numbers in the file.

Comment: You are not initializing `line`. See the initialization of `iss` in the duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/487892

Comment: Yyes I checked it it worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just stream directly into your variables instead of using `getline`

Like so:

```
YourStream >> YearInt >> YourDouble;
```

Just using a `getline` at the beginning to get rid of the header.

Comment: Hey I updated my post with your advice. I used Stringstream but Now I get negative random numbers instead of the numbers in the file.